# Django left join or analog

Tags: django, django-orm

I can't figure out how to use Django ORM for left joins, please see case below.

My models are (please, don't mind native language):

```
class Production(models.Model):
    '''Выработка.'''
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='проект')
    timeperiod = models.ForeignKey(
        Timeperiod, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='период')
    time = models.DurationField('трудочасы')
    amount = models.DecimalField('выработка', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    note = models.TextField('заметка', blank=True, null=True)
    is_auto = models.BooleanField(
        'признак автоматического расчета', default=False)

class Timeperiod(models.Model):
    '''Периоды.'''
    start_date = models.DateField('дата начала')
    end_date = models.DateField('дата окончания')
    target_duration = models.DurationField('длительность')
    is_open = models.BooleanField('открыт', default=True)
```

I would like to make following selection:

1. Get all the Timeperiod with filters on start_date and end_date
2. Get related Production with filter on project (if any exists for this particular period)

Pass it to template_processor and render it as a table (in for loop)

I know how to filter queryset, and know how to get related queryset, but I don’t understand how to filter my RELATED queryset

**UPDATE**

I want queryset that should be just like this SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM collector_timeperiod tp
LEFT JOIN collector_production AS p ON p.timeperiod_id = tp.id 
                                    AND p.project_id = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the related model with `timeperiod__…`, for example:

```
Production.objects.filter(
    timeperiod__start_date__gte='2022-3-1',
    timeperiod__end_date__lte='2022-3-31'
)
```

or if you want to retrieve the `Project`s:

```
Project.objects.filter(
    production__timeperiod__start_date__gte='2022-3-1',
    production__timeperiod__end_date__lte='2022-3-31'
).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will avoid retrieving the same `Project` that many times as there are matching `Timeperiod`s.

Comment: Yes, it is, but it is not what I want - I want ALL desired Timeperiods with related and filtered Production, I want to go from the Timeperiods, if I go from productions - I will not get all desired periods

Comment: @garikf: but your `Product` has a `ForeignKey` to `Timeperiod`, not in reverse, so one `Product` has exactly one `Timeperiod`, not *multiple* ones?

Comment: Yes, because one timeperiod allowed to have one related production per specific project, that is why I wanted to filter projects in my queryset

Comment: @garikf: then you filter with `production__timeperiod__...`. See update.

Comment: How do I access Periods in template, if I querying Productions? I can get related Periods related to queried Productions, but I don’t get all periods, and this is my case

Comment: I have added SQL query that reflects what ORM expression I would like to make